# Push Notification based on SQL Server database Table Data

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications

We have a sql server table with some sort of data, we like to send sms notification to our mobile app users.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: What do you mean by SMS notification? A SMS or app notification.

Comment: app notification as well as SMS

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send a push notification on an android device, the best way to do this is to use [GCM(Google Cloud Messeging)](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/).

The real technique that, add the client id of the user in sql table and while adding data to the sql, just send them a push.

[Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) to add GCM on androi.